# What is this part of the fermentation called?

Tags: fermentation, yeast

I'm seeing this thing happen soon after I add my yeast and was wondering what it was called and the science behind it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"High Krausen"/"Exponential Growth Phase"
As the yeast feeds it produces co2 and the bubbles make a foam of yeast and other materials in the beer.

Answer (score 3):

How soon is "soon"?

It looks like you've sprinkled dry yeast across the top of your (chilled) brew kettle and maybe waited 10-20 minutes? If so, this is the yeast "blooming" in response to being reactivated from their dried state. At what temperature is the wort? Can you provide any more detail about your process?

Comment: Wort is at room temperature.

Comment: Looks like a lot of yeast for it to be from dry yeast, no?  Maybe OP is using three packets.